# Regex pattern mismatches while checking time format

Tags: c#, regex, time-format

I would love to accept the following formats:

```
"23:59", "2:3:04", "02:00:09", "23:07:00"
```

with this regex pattern:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(timeIn, @"^([0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9])|([0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9])$") ? true : false;
```

unfortunately it accepts other formats as well, e.g.: 00:00:99

what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Write a better title.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: "((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a set of enclosing parenthesis for the whole expression, between the start of line and end of line anchors:

```
 ^(([0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9])|([0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]))$
```

Without the enclosing parenthesis, your regex was essentially saying:

- match `^([0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9])`
- or    `([0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9])$`

So, `00:00:99` would be valid, matching against the first part of the regex. And, so would something like: `99:00:00:00`, which would match against the second part.

That said, your regex is still going to match some unwanted patterns, such as: `29:00`

An improved version would be:

```
^((([0-1]?[0-9])|(2[0-3]):[0-5]?[0-9])|(([0-1]?[0-9])|(2[0-3]):[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]))$
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it does not answer the question directly, I would like to say that in such a standard cases, I would rather use built-in function rather than creating real scary regular expressions:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "H:m:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
```